# Roofing nails protruding in attic dripping with condensation

Tags: attic, roofing

After a re-roofing job there are hundreds of nail points sticking out in the attic. I use some of the attic space for storage so when standing up in there I get poked in the head, but also in freezing weather, these nails drip from condensation and get all my stuff wet. Can I cut off the nails and then put a dollop of silicone sealant on the little bit still sticking inside to insulate the nail from the warmer moister air in the attic so it won't drip? Or would that cause the moisture to soak up into the sheathing and lead to rot?

Comment: How is this warm-moist air getting into your attic in the first place? Do you have a vent that isn't exhausting outside?

Comment: Thanks to all 3 of you who answered! Yes I think I have a ventilation problem and I'm going to work on that too. A bonus room remodel that was done by a previous owner stuffed the spaces between the roof and the ceiling with insulation blocking the air flow up to the ridge vents. So in addition to clipping off the nails and dabbing them with silicone, I plan to replace all the thick fiberglass with 2 inch Styrofoam with a good 1-1/2" gap under the roof sheathing. Does that sound like a good plan? THANKS!

Comment: Tom, please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand what's expected of you on this site. It's better to not ask new questions in comments. You could revise your question, but it's maybe better to ask a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Roofing ails are supposed to protrude, at least a bit. That's how they achieve much of their pullout resistance. It's a bit odd that they didn't before.

Feel free to stick whatever you like on them to protect your head. If they're dripping that much, though, you're sorely lacking in attic ventilation. Protecting the nails doesn't do anything for the wood throughout the attic.

Comment: I'll have to concur. One other thing to note... Improper ventilation will reduce the life of your shingles as well.